# Squid:Compilation Error for squid-3.HEAD due to ssl

Tags: c++, proxy, openssl, fedora, squid

I am trying to build squid-3.HEAD on Fedora 13 but i am getting the
following compilation errors.

```
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -  I../..../../include -I../../lib -I../../src -I../../include
-I../../libltdl   -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wcomments
 -Werror -pipe -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -std=c++0x -MT Acl.lo -MD -MP -MF
 .deps/Acl.Tpo -c -o Acl.lo Acl.cc

libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../.. -I../../include
-I../../lib -I../../src -I../../include -I../../libltdl -Wall
-Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wcomments -Werror -pipe -D_REENTRANT
-g -O2 -std=c++0x -MT Acl.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/Acl.Tpo -c Acl.cc
-fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/Acl.o

In file included from ../../src/ProtoPort.h:12:0,
             from Acl.cc:40:

/src/ssl/gadgets.h:57:1: error: variable or field 'TXT_DB_free_cpp'
declared void
../../src/ssl/gadgets.h:57:1: error: 'TXT_DB' was not declared in this scope
../../src/ssl/gadgets.h:57:1: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
../../src/ssl/gadgets.h:58:21: error: 'TXT_DB' was not declared in this scope
../../src/ssl/gadgets.h:58:29: error: 'TXT_DB_free_cpp' was not
declared in this scope
../../src/ssl/gadgets.h:58:44: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../../src/ssl/gadgets.h:58:44: error: template argument 2 is invalid
../../src/ssl/gadgets.h:58:60: error: invalid type in declaration
before ';' token
```

Openssl and openssl-devel are already installed and with latest versions

Gcc(g++) version = 4.4.5
OpenSSL version = 1.0.0d-1.fc13.i686

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem on voyage/Debian. Somewhere I have read you should try an older version.